# Secure Server is not receiving what I am sending

Tags: c#, windows, ssl

I am trying to connect to server via *TLS 1* on Windows.

here is how I am connecting to server

```
public void Connect(string hostName, int port)
    {
        this.tcpClient.Client.Connect(hostName, port);

        RemoteCertificateValidationCallback validationCallback = new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ServerValidationCallback);
        LocalCertificateSelectionCallback selectionCallback = new LocalCertificateSelectionCallback(ClientCertificateSelectionCallback);
        EncryptionPolicy encryptionPolicy = EncryptionPolicy.RequireEncryption;

        this.sslStream = new SslStream(this.tcpClient.GetStream(), true, validationCallback, selectionCallback, encryptionPolicy);

        //handshake 
        X509CertificateCollection clientCertificates = GetCertificates();

        this.sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(hostName);
        //this.sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(hostName, clientCertificates, SslProtocols.Tls, true);
    }
```

Than I am sending messages via method

```
this.sslStream.Write(messageBytes);
this.sslStream.Flush();
this.tcpClient.GetStream().Flush();
```

Server did not receiving anything from me.

Comment: Server did not receive anything how? With what code?

Comment: I do not have much access to server. They just do not receive messages from my client. Server is not mine, I do not have a code. I am writing a Windows client for it. Server automatically disconnects and I am receiving connection lost message (remote host forcefully disconnected) because it is not receiving message from me in some period of time.

Comment: At a guess the server is reading lines and you aren't sending lines. Try adding a newline to the end of the message. Otherwise you're just going to have to get more information about the server.

Comment: I am not sending a text. I am sending binary by using Google Protocol Buffer. There is no line.